# Propagate exception caught during Display.syncExec to invoking thread

Tags: java, concurrency, swt

A Pattern that I've seen a few times now and still am unsure if it's correct: I need to invoke some code on the SWT UI thread via Display.syncExec. The code that runs in the UI thread catches a checked exception and wants to propagate this exception to the waiting thread. The pattern looks like this:

```
SomeCheckedException[] exc = new SomeCheckedException[] { null };
display.syncExec(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      try {
         new Work().something();
      } catch (SomeCheckedException e){
         exc[0] = e;
      }
   }
});

if (exc[0] != null){
 //..
}
```

Even if there's no real concurrency here, I still think that this is not really safe in terms of visibility: It could well happen that the UI thread stores an exception, but the invoking thread won't see this and still read 'null' when accessing the array after taking control again. Am I right? Is the best way then just to catch SWTException and check its throwable field via `instanceof`? EDIT: Hm, that won't work so easy if it's a checked exception. I'd need to throw the SWTException from the catch block myself. Better solutions?

Thanks for your help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of case [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) was made for:

```
  void foo() throws SomeCheckedException {
    final AtomicReference<SomeCheckedException> exRef = new AtomicReference<>();
    display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          new Work().something();
        } catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
          exRef.set(e);
        }
      }
    });
    SomeCheckedException ex = exRef.get();
    if (ex != null) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is real concurrency here, because the UI Thread is a different Thread than your main Thread. This will most definitely result in exc[0] to be null.

You have to synchronize the access to the array if you want your main Thread to wait until the UI Thread has filled put the exception in there. And you need to time that as well. Probably your main Thread will have to check over and over again until it is filled. Or you could suspend it (sleep) and let the UI Thread wake it up (notify).

EDIT: Solution for a waiting Thread, without notify, simply sleeps for a few milliseconds, then checks.

```
//object properties
volatile Exception e = null;
volatile Exception completed = false;
...
display.syncExec(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try
        {
          ...
          e = thrownException;
          ....
        } catch (...){};
        //must be after the try block:
        completed = true;
    }
...
while(! completed)
    Thread.sleep(500) //or something, lookup the javadoc
//after the while ends, you can safely access e
```

Comment: FYI: [syncExec](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#syncExec%28java.lang.Runnable%29) blocks until the task has been executed on the UI thread; there is no need for the while loop.